# Bootstrap 4 fixed image height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap's 4 grid system to display randomly sized image from unsplash.com into a web-page.

The issue I have is that I do not know how can I make a fixed sized thumbnail for all images, regardless of their height but at the same time fit it into it's container.

Here is a sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-5 py-3 py-md-5">
    <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
          <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
          <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
          <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
          <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    const imageCards = document.querySelectorAll(".image-card");
    const url = "https://source.unsplash.com/collection/308700/300/?sig=";

    const randomNum = () => {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    };

    for (let image of imageCards) {
      let src = `${url}${randomNum()}`;
      image.setAttribute("src", src);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Sample]

Is there any bootstrap specific class I can apply to have the same image height and also fit it into it's parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [padding top trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to give me the aspect ratio of the image and then I can absolutely position the image inside the anchor and use [object fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) on it (may need a polyfill for ie):

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* use classes instead of these element selectors */

a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

a>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mt-5 py-3 py-md-5">
  <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
        <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
        <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
        <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Galerie" asp-action="FotoNunta">
        <img class="image-card img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/400" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be setting a height to the img-thumbnail and then giving it a object-fit:

```
<style>
.img-thumbnail {
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```